# Shrouded Sonnets on the Sable Tablet

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, poetry, mazes

Enter from the north and traverse the path unseen.

Left, right, up, or down, your choices shall glean.

With each step, leave not your path behind,

For only those who dare to venture shall find.

So tread upon every tile, as destiny's path unfolds,

With each step, unraveling the enigmas the temple holds.

And when the final tile is reached, a sense of awe will arise,

For you have conquered the puzzle, revealing its grand prize.

[image: maze]

Comment: Can you cross your own path? Or is this strictly a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: No, and Yes it is a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: See many paths. Trying to find more clues in the poem...

Comment: I have already found a Hamiltonian; are there supposed to be just one, or multiple?

Comment: @newQOpenWid: You can probably modify paths to get slightly different ones. I think the puzzle is to find out what the prize is. My guess is that there is one "good" path that rot13(sbezf yrggref be funcrf), or that rot13(pbeerfcbaqf gb gur cbrz fbzrubj).